# Cannot load checkpoints

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I taught a model ([tensorflow tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ysEKrw_LE2jMndo1snrZUh5w87LQsCxk#forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true)) in Jupyter then saved it, then succesfully loaded it back (kernel was restarted). Here's the code:

```
# Directory where the checkpoints will be saved
checkpoint_dir = '/home/charlie-chin/william_model/training_checkpoints'
# Name of the checkpoint files
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")

checkpoint_callback=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
    save_weights_only=True)

model.save('/home/charlie-chin/william_model')

model = keras.models.load_model('/home/charlie-chin/william_model', custom_objects={'loss':loss})

checkpoint_num = 10
model.load_weights(tf.train.Checkpoint("/home/charlie-chin/william_model/training_checkpoints/ckpt_" + str(checkpoint_num)))
```

All went good except the last 2 lines which gave me this error:

```
ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting root to be a trackable object (an object derived from `Trackable`), got /home/charlie-chin/william_model/training_checkpoints/ckpt_1. If you believe this object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.
```

I checked the path - it is correct. Here's full output of the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [39], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 checkpoint_num = 10
      2 # model.load_weights(tf.train.load_checkpoint("./william_model/training_checkpoints/ckpt_"))
      3 # model.load_weights(tf.train.Checkpoint("/home/charlie-chin/william_model/training_checkpoints/ckpt_" + str(checkpoint_num)+".data-00000-of-00001"))
----> 4 model.load_weights(tf.train.Checkpoint("/home/charlie-chin/william_model/training_checkpoints/ckpt_" + str(checkpoint_num)))

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py:2107, in Checkpoint.__init__(self, root, **kwargs)
   2105 if root:
   2106   trackable_root = root() if isinstance(root, weakref.ref) else root
-> 2107   _assert_trackable(trackable_root, "root")
   2108   attached_dependencies = []
   2110   # All keyword arguments (including root itself) are set as children
   2111   # of root.

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py:1546, in _assert_trackable(obj, name)
   1543 def _assert_trackable(obj, name):
   1544   if not isinstance(
   1545       obj, (base.Trackable, def_function.Function)):
-> 1546     raise ValueError(
   1547         f"`Checkpoint` was expecting {name} to be a trackable object (an "
   1548         f"object derived from `Trackable`), got {obj}. If you believe this "
   1549         "object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the "
   1550         "TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.")

ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting root to be a trackable object (an object derived from `Trackable`), got /home/charlie-chin/william_model/training_checkpoints/ckpt_10. If you believe this object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to load the checkpoints according to the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load?hl=en#manually_save_weights) like this:

```
checkpoint_num = 10
model.load_weights("/home/charlie-chin/william_model/training_checkpoints/ckpt_" + str(checkpoint_num))
```